# Replace dashes in cell with asterisks in concatenated result

Tags: excel, vba

I'm concatenating columns into a single string.

The problem is the SKU col, that also includes dashes, when dashes are used to separate columns.

So I'd like to replace dashes with asterics in result:

From: `ppl-lal-myproduct-s-fd334343-09-otro`

To: `ppl-lal-myproduct-s*fd334343*09-otro`

[image]

Comment: Check SUBSTITUTE and TEXTJOIN. With SUBSTITUTE you should be able to replace the dash. Then TEXTJOIN will join all strings into single cell, and you can choose dash as delimiter

Comment: If the range where you try concatenate its cells value would be "C5:G5", try the next way of replacing: Range("C5:G5").Replace "-", "*"`. Concatenate after that...

Comment: Why don't you share the code or formula you're currently using?

Answer (score 1):

A VBA solution to do replacing and concatenation would be the next:

```
   Dim arr1D
   With Range("C5:G5")
        .Replace "-", "*"
        arr1D = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value2)) 'make 1D array form a row range
   End With
   Debug.Print Join(arr1D, "-")
```